# Installation failed with Android Studio, APK not signed

Tags: android, gradle

Recently change to Android Studio from Eclipse and I have also changed the JDK from `java-open-jdk` to `jdk1.7.0_45`.

Now I'm trying to run my first app and I get this message:

```
Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration 
is specified in the Gradle build script
```

**Edit:**

When I'm running from Android Studio I get the error displayed above. When I'm running it from the command line I don't get an error (well the app is running and I get an error but nothing to do with gradle).

I got the code from [here](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html)

You can check build.gradle here at [google repo](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/build.gradle?repo=samples)

**UPDATE 2:**

I added this code

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("john.keystore")
        storePassword "john"
        keyAlias "johnkeystore"
        keyPassword "john"
    }
}
```

just above the `buildTypes` code block in the build.gradle file.
File john.keystore is on the root of my Project. I'm running `gradlew assembleRelease` and I'm getting a  `xxx-release-unsigned.apk`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you indeed runing build with gradle you need to configure `signingConfigs`. Android can configure your debug signingConfig automatically. You can make release `signingConfig` in a next manner:

```
android {

    signingConfigs {

        release {

            storeFile file('android.keystore')
            storePassword "pwd"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "pwd"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

       release {

           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
    }
}
```

Check manual on this topic here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations

If you still have issues, please update question with your `build.gradle`. Most likely issue is laying here. I'm using JDK 1.7 and gradle builds are working fine.

Comment: It looks like you did not register added `signingConfig` at your release build type. Like this: http://pastebin.com/VbaW9Hyz

Comment: That did the trick. Now I have tasks-android-sample-release.apk and tasks-android-sample-release-unaligned.apk .Hope the first one is the one I need unless it must explicitly contain the word signed in the apk's name?

Comment: You are right, `-release.apk` is all set. You can double check that .apk has signing indeed by running next command `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs tasks-android-sample-release.apk`. You should see `jar verified` output for signed apks.

Comment: Android Studio 0.5.2 put the signing config BELOW the build variant in my build.gradle. Manually moving the signingConfigs container ABOVE fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, i went to Build->Clean Project and re-execute the project and it worked.

Comment: For me re-sync-ing the project solved the problem after switching between build variants.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling for a while with Android Studio esp. gradle and build variants.

I have change this from the build types as defined:

```
debug
release
```

Answer (score 0):

As I ran into the same problem (while developing and running tests), I went to  `Build -> Rebuild Project` and then re-launched the emulator. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me, even after uninstalling app from phone, I could not deploy it. What worked was installing the app o a different device, and then when I tried to deploy it on the previous device, it miracleously worked.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is not to create a custom build for your application you might want to clean all the data about it from your test device, in case you are using emulator just wipe all the data from device. Go to -> `Tools` -> `Android` -> `AVD Manager` -> [Device you wanna wipe] (In actions tab) -> `Wipe Data`.

[image]

In case of actual device just uninstall the app and all related data.

Reason is that unsigned APK has a signature, so device sees you're trying to install something with the same package name that was generated not here.

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

In case your device has multiple users, before installing signed APK, check if the same app is not installed for other users. If it is there remove it.

For me this was the root cause of rejecting installation of signed APK.

Answer (score 0):

**Just to Build -> Rebuild Project and then re-launched the emulator. That worked for me.**