# Application Installation Failed, build script error

Tags: android, gradle, build, installation, apk

Here , I have added latest google play services(com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0), gradle(com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha). I get the following error on installation in my device.

[image]
Here is the app build.gradle content.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.properties'
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wolfmatrix.navz"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
```

}

Comment: did you sign your app apk??

Comment: Yes not for release.

Answer (score 1):

**Error shows that apk is signed incorrectly**

Try this -

1) Delete your signed apk from **"{WORKSPACE} \ {YOUR APP FOLDER}\app\build\outputs\apk"**.

2) uninstall your app from device.

3) run project over USB debugging to create app-debug.apk

4) after successful build you can sign your app apk for release.

Hope it will help :)

**UPDATE**

Check this - [Installation failed with Android Studio, APK not signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612628/installation-failed-with-android-studio-apk-not-signed)